# Better tip to write python program to mix split and join

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written the following code:

```
 with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
     #sending second line to variable port1
     port1 = (f.readlines()[1])
     # Make proper space 
     port1 = " ".join(port1.split())
     print port1
     # fetch eth0 to port1 variable
     port1 = port1.split(" ")[1]
     print port1
```

`inputfile.txt` contains:

```
  server port1 port2
  server1  eth1    eth2
  server2  eth7    eth8
```

Above code is working fine. I am getting expected results.

But code seems not to be standard. I used `port1` multiple times. Is there any better way to write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the split and join again "game" as follows:

```
with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
     #sending second line to variable port1
     port1 = f.readlines()[1]
     # prepare for further processing:
     port1 = port1.split()
     # Print with proper space 
     print " ".join(port1)
     # print eth1 (your input data has no eth0)
     print port1[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's better, but another way to go about it might be to yield each line, if you know how many lines there are:

```
def get_conf(fn='inputfile.txt'):
    with open(fn) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            yield line.split()

c = get_conf()
s, p1, p2 = next(c)
s1, a1, b1 = next(c)
s2, a2, b2 = next(c)
```